# Java Recursion Fun Test Error

Tags: java, tail-recursion

I am currently trying to recursively print all sums of subsets for an input of numbers. For each number, I recursively print all possible sums of the numbers after it without adding it in, then I print all possible sums of the numbers after it with the number added in.
For example, I take an input of (1 2 3) and receive an output of (0 3 2 5 2 6 3 6) where the first half is all sums achievable without the 1, the second half, with.

I managed to do it but it isn't universal for other solutions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> given = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> empty = new ArrayList<>();
    while(scan.hasNext()) {
        given.add(scan.nextInt());
    }
    int temp = given.size();
    recurse(given, empty, temp);
}

public static void recurse(ArrayList<Integer> given, ArrayList<Integer> empty, int temp) {
    if(empty.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println(0);
        empty.add(given.get(temp - 1));
        temp--;
        recurse(given,empty,temp);

    }

    if(empty.size() == 1) {
        empty.add(given.get(temp));

        System.out.println(given.get(temp));
        temp--;
    }

    if(empty.size() < given.size()) {
        empty.add(given.get(temp));
        System.out.println(given.get(temp));
        for(int c = empty.size() - 1; c > 0; c--) {
            System.out.println(empty.get(c) * empty.get(c-1));
        }

    }
}
```

I was wondering on how I can print all the subsets that don't involve the first element, then print all the subset sums that do in that specific order which is the main thing that is tripping me.

Comment: for the input `1 2 3` your code does not produce `0 3 2 5 1 4 3 6` but `0 3 2 6 9`

Comment: oh oops, i pasted my code after i was messing around but still, I just can't seem to grasp the idea on how to do this.

Comment: `if(empty.size() == 1)` suggests that you could think harder about the names of your variables!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me first admit that I've failed to understand how your code is supposed to work; the purpose of `empty` and `temp`, or why you are multiplying at the end.

Recursive algorithms on lists are much easier to think about if you make the methods functional, in the sense that they treat their parameters as immutable and have no side effects.

As soon as you make a recursive method make any changes to non-local state, the whole thing becomes more difficult to reason about.

So write `List<Integer> subsetSums(List<Integer> numbers)` -- you don't need any other parameters.

The guard clause is easy:

```
  if(numbers.isEmpty()) {
      return Collections.emptyList();
  }
```

The recursive clause is:

```
  List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i = 0; i<numbers.size(); i++) {
      results.addAll(subsetSums(new ListWithout(numbers, i));
  }
  results.add(sum(numbers));
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(results);
```

You don't *have* to use `Collections.unmodifiableList()` here, but it helps detect mistakes at runtime -- modifying one of these lists is a bug.

This uses a custom class `ListWithout` which provides a view over the list, skipping one element. This saves repeatedly copying the whole list.

```
public class ListWithout extends AbstractList<Integer> {
   private final List<Integer> parent;
   private final int elementToRemove;

   public ListWithout(List<Integer> parent, int elementToRemove) {
       this.parent = parent;
       this.elementToRemove = elementToRemove;
   }

   @Override
   public int size() {
      return parent.size() - 1;
   }

   @Override
   public Integer get(int index) {
      if(index >= elementToRemove) {
          index++;
      }
      return parent.get(index);
   }
```

This returns `[3, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 6]`

... which is:

- the sums possible without using the `1`, `[ 3, 2, 5]`
- the sums possible without using the `2`, `[ 3, 1, 4]`
- the sums possible without using the `3`, `[ 2, 1, 3]`
- the sum using all elements, `[6]`

You can make the order of the output list more pleasing (in my eyes) by reversing the direction of the `for` loop, so it counts downward from `size()-1` to `0` instead of upward. Then you get: `[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6]`

---

This has repeats in it, and the key to avoiding this is, as you've noted:

- Find all the combinations not containing the first element
- Then find all the combinations that do contain the first element

Notice that once you know the first set, you can easily construct the second set just by adding the first element to each of these (and zero).

So:

```
public List<Integer> sublistSums(List<Integer> numbers) {
    if (numbers.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Integer> sumsOfTail = sublistSums(numbers.subList(1, numbers.size()));
    results.addAll(sumsOfTail);
    results.addAll(addToAll(numbers.get(0), sumsOfTail));

    return Collections.unmodifiableList(results);
}
```

I'll leave `addToAll(int num, List<Integer> list)` to you, but it should return a list of integers made by adding `num` to each member of `list`, and also `num` itself. i.e. `addToAll(3, [4,5]) -> [3,7,8]`.

Comment: i see. one thing where is sum from in " results.add(sum(numbers)); " that is in the recursive clause?

Comment: You will need to write your own `int sum(List<Integer> list)`. Very easy.

Comment: ah got it. i'm still having trouble figuring out how to get that specific output (0 3 2 5 1 4 3 6). The input and output is right, but I left out one detail for the output by accident. Sorry the full description is the first half is all the sums achievable without the 1, the second half, with. The first quarter and third quarter don't include the 2, but the other quarters do. I didn't think the second description was important.

Comment: OK, I think you have enough of a framework here to achieve that. Just make recursive clause do what you said: `results.addAll(combosContainingFirstElement(numbers)); results.addAll(combosNotContainingFirstElement(numbers));` - with the tools you've now got, it shouldn't be too hard to write those routines.

Comment: Sorry i was working on it. Thank you so much. Got it finally. Sorry I am new to java haha.